# My android dontpanic folder is too big. can I delete stuff from it?

Tags: android

I have gone through the usual process of googling and found that in android /data/dontpanic folder contains crash logs. Now my question is this. How safe is it to delete files from that folder? If it is safe then how can I do that ?my phone is rooted .

Answer (score 0):

You can connect the device to your computer and just go to the folder and delete or copy the file.
Another option is to download the file explorer app and access the file requested.

Comment: OK so do you know if it is safe ? Will android misbehave if I delete  the files ?

Comment: This folder contains information on crashes that happened.
No problem to delete the information, this information only.

Comment: I used fx file explorer with root extension and deleted the files. It seems to have worked.

Comment: There should be no problem.